# Why does (python -m ...) result in sys.argv like ['-c', ...]

Tags: python

I have a simple script test.py

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

If I run

`python test.py abcd`in cmd,

I will get ['test.py', 'abcd'].

However, if I run

```
python -m test.py abcd
```

I will get

```
['-c', 'abcd']

E:\Program Files (x86)\py\python.exe: No module named test.py.
```

Why is `'-c'` here? I searched Stack Overflow about the use of `'-m'` but still confused.

Comment: So why are you trying to run with `-m test.py` in the first place?

Comment: `man python` mentions interesting things about `-m` and `-c`.

Comment: `-m` expects the next string to be the module name so it can search the sys.path for the corresponding `.py` file to run. So when you try `python -m test.py abcd` python is looking for a module named `test.py` to run `test.py.py`. These do not exist so it pukes. You can read this information in the man pages/help file for python.

Comment: I am trying to learn Python so I tried this '-m' option..

Comment: If you really want to learn then you should be utilizing the documentation available. Trying things out is awesome and a great way to learn, but so is reading the manual. If you are in linux it's as easy as `man python` or visit the python site.

Comment: @scrappedcola: The `-c` behaviour is a little surprising though, and not documented until you go looking for source code and bug reports..

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. The document is great but sometimes too 'dry' for me. I think I need to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-m` switch tells python to look for a *module or package* to import and run it's `__main__` entry. See the [`-m` switch documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.

For your case, that means Python is looking for a *package* called `test.py` (note: **not** a *file* with that name). To find it, Python first imports the module `test` (from your `test.py` file), to look for a sub-module named `py`. This fails. But in that process your `test` module is still run and prints out `sys.argv`.

The `-c` switch in the `sys.argv` list is an internal implementation detail of how this process works. See [Python issue #8202](http://bugs.python.org/issue8202) for some of the details:

> As I recall, I used a bit of a hack to get `main.c` to implement `-m` correctly by piggybacking on the existing `-c` semantics. I'll find the hack and replace it with some proper `'-c'` or `'-m'` logic.

If you want to use the `-m` switch you'll need to drop the `.py` part; that's just the file extension, not the module name:

```
python -m test abcd
```